# WPF Application loses focus when sub menu closed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menu and sub-menu in wpf application, when remove mouse pointer from submenu item, the application lost it's focus. For example, button hover does not work properly on. But when i click on empty area of application, then button hover effect works properly.

**Expected behaviour is that, button should not lose it's style/action.**

[image]

hover effect : [image]

without hover effect : [image]

control template as follow

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                       Focusable="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2,10,0,0">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF666565"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFE0D3D3"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="IsOpen" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" >
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFDDDDDD"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you using some framework for the UI or only bare WPF?

Comment: I am using raw WPF

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you don't mean, the application loses the focus (as it does not, which you can see when you hit e. g. TAB), but nothing but the opened submenue and the corresponding main menu reacts to the mouse.

This is the standard behaviour in WPF applications, when a popup is opened. It's the same when you open a context menue. And it's the same in WinForms applications.

You can check this as well in Visual Studio.

**EDIT**

So we have an app mainmenue

[image]

When you click a menueitem and move the mouse (no button pressed) across the submenue you get this

[image]

and after moving (still no button pressed, just moving) all the way down beneath the submenu

[image]

the submenu closes? If that is true, you should look at the menues definition (and maybe post it here) as this is no standard menue behaviour.

Comment: my concern is that, when i open a submenu and move cursor from submenu item, the submenu becomes closed, after that i put cursor on a button on same window, but button hover styling (e.g. mouse-pointer= cursor) does not work

Comment: Could always link to the LostFocus for that menu/menu item collection and close it in code behind, or something to that effect